# Profile Image Harvesting with bigint ID's

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-injection

I have a large volume of images that are currently ID'd by GUID's (this is a requirement for `FILESTREAM` tables in SQL Server).

However, these are horrible for indexing. I'm looking at using a `bigint` to ID them but I feel that this would make my database vulnerable to profile harvesting.

What's the best practice here? Can I alleviate profile harvesting concerns somehow?

*by "profile-harvesting" I mean somebody's ability to download/store all images by being able to predict the next ID

Comment: It isn't that GUIDs are a poor choice for an index. It is a concern however when they are the clustered index because they will get too 99.99% fragmented with as few as a few thousand rows. This is easily handled by simply defragmenting your index on this table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It a lot depends on how you allow access to your content to your users. If you are giving permissions based access to your users then you may limit them through a database entity specifying what resources are available to which users.

For general resource leeching, a good article is available on the topic here [how-to-prevent-the-resource-leech-from-a-website](http://rahulrajatsingh.com/2014/06/how-to-prevent-the-resource-leech-from-a-website/). Code in this article could be modified to protect images i.e. resources ending with .jpg, .png etc.

As another option you could use Temporary Download URLs. An article for implementing the same could be found here [Generating Temporary Download URLs](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/a22aaa2f-1c0a-41ba-98bf-faf3351e2f91.aspx)

If you are providing your resources through a HttpHandler you may use an encrypted temporary url parameter which expires after a specific time period.

Implementation of these methods is primarily based on how you provide access to your resources.

Comment: HTTP handler. Encrypted temporary URL parameter is what I was looking for. Thank you.